# How do I verify a call to a static method in a final class using jMockit and TestNG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, jmockit

How do I verify a call to a static method in a final class using jMockit?

In PowerMockito, this isn't possible because the class is final. If this can't be done using jMockit, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do it in PowerMockito, yes.

Anyway, in JMockit, you usually would write a *verification* block like the following:

```
@Test
public void exampleTest(@Mocked AFinalClass mock)
{
    // Call the code under test which uses AFinalClass.

    new Verifications() {{ AFinalClass.someStaticMethod(); }};
}
```

Comment: How does TestNG know how to mock @Mocked annotated arguments?

Comment: By itself, it doesn't; when using JMockit, the JMockit-TestNG integration takes care of that.

Comment: The critical part of this answer is including the `@Mocked AFinalClass mock` parameter. I have a mix of MockUp, withCapture, and static that I'm trying to test and including the parameter was what finally got things working for me. Too bad the documentation isn't clearer about this...

Answer (score 0):

Below is my version based on `@Mocked` and `MockUp`

```java
public class Util {
    static {
        // static initializer
    }

    public static void doSomething(String arg) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

```java
public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void testDoSomething(@Mocked Util util) {
        // NOTE: need to move the `MockUp` to @BeforeClass method if you want to mock the static initializer
        new MockUp<Util>() {
            @Mock
            void $clinit() {
                // do nothing
            }

            @Mock
            void doSomething(String arg) {
                // mock doSomething
            }
        };

        // action to test

        // verify
        new Verifications() {{
            String arg;
            Util.doSomething(arg = withCapture());
            assertEquals("expected", arg);
        }};
    }
}
```